# Visual Studio web publish log

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible in Visual Studio to view a log of when a website was published? We had a situation where the directory for our website was deleted with the exception of a "styles" subfolder.

Trying to determine if it was a failed publish by Visual Studio or another cause. The remaining "styles" folder had a last modified date so it would be helpful to know if it matched with the Publish time.